# Output Parameter With Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am new to and getting used to LINQ. I have worked with SPROCS that return result sets. No problems there.

However I am having a problem with OUTPUT params & LINQ.

the stored procedure i simple enough

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCNAME] 
 -- Add the parameters for the 
stored procedure here
   @tcStageOccurrences smallint output

 SELECT @tcStageOccurrences =
           isnull(COUNT(*),0) from 
           Stage where Condition
```

I am calling this in C# as follows

```
System.Nullable<Int16> tcStageOccurences = null; 
MyDb.ProcName(ref @tcStageOccurrences);
```

The value of @tcStageOccurrences is 0 whereas it should be >0

**Questions**

1. I have always used SQLparam & ExcuteReader or ExecuteNonQuery without any problems.
   Since I am trying to do the same thing in LINQ, is there something I am missing out?

I know that i can and probably should be using a scalar function instead.

But in some cases there are multiple OUTPUT parameters that I need to access within C#

Any help or useful tips are most welcome :-)

Regards

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the tip! How do I accept an answer!! let me check

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer to this after thinking this one over and well it involved some experimenting as well.

This is what i did:

1. Declared an internal / temp  variable with type `smallint`
2. Assigned the count value of the select statement to this variable
3. Assigned the temp variable's value to my output parameter

This works!

Any further comments etc are welcome!!